# What, exactly, happened to The Base Camp and all the other Chat Rooms?

Tags: discussion

What, **exactly**, happened to The Base Camp and the other chat rooms?

The Base Camp, which I followed regularly, disappeared in the wake of The Mess.  I saw no incitement to riot or other bad behavior in TGO's Chat Room, only disappointment at the course of events.  Ditto for the ELU Chat Room, which, like ELU as a whole, seemed oblivious to the entire imbroglio.

Yet, as far as I can tell, someone decided TGO and the other chat rooms had done something wrong and deleted them.

If I have just overlooked a link to The Base Camp, abject apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unsure if you perhaps tried to access a chat room during a small outage, but I have not been able to recreate the problem. All chat rooms still exist, and my presence in 39 of them has not been affected.

To access it, just select the hamburger icon at the top right and select chat, or use the link:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2291/the-base-camp

Comment: I agree, I have had the Basecamp on my chat list and have never not been able to enter. It has gone mostly dead but that is an other problem.